# Host ionic 3 app on IIS?

Tags: iis, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am deploying my app on IIS but it is not working. What I am doing is run the command `ionic build browser` and host the www folder on IIS. When I run the hosted website I got two error. One is cordova.js is not found and the other one is in my service that object(....) is not a function. I have tried many things but it's not working. Below are the error i got on brwoser console:

```
cordova.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
event-service.ts:6 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Object.605 (event-service.ts:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b338a5eb2d97a44eede9:54)
    at Object.37 (index.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b338a5eb2d97a44eede9:54)
    at Object.157 (index.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b338a5eb2d97a44eede9:54)
    at Object.exports.isScheduler (ArrayObservable.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b338a5eb2d97a44eede9:54)
    at Object.exports.isArrayLike (merge.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b338a5eb2d97a44eede9:54)
```

Can anyone tell what i missing or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall node and delete node_modules and run npm install resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

try running the project with cordova:

> ionic cordova run browser

to build the project:

> ionic cordova build browser